# How to Get Pages That Are Opened in Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write an extension for Google Chrome. My extension will need info about opened tabs, actually, I want to know, for instance, in tab[1], http://www.google.com is open.

How I will achieve this, thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add `"tabs"` to your `permissions` in your `manifest.json` file. Then, you can simply use the [`chrome.tabs.query`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) function and specify no properties to get all the tabs.

Some sample code would look like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query(null, function (tab){
    console.log(tab[0].url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but, how do I use chrome.tabs api? I added your code to my code file, nothing happened.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to `console.log` it. :P. Try opening the file wherever you put the code in the console. It should tell you the first tab's URL.