# How do I dynamically change the background.js to reflect a user's setting in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I am developing a chrome extension right now in order to get introduced to the world of web development. I have run into a issue which I can't seem to get my head wrapped around. Currently, my background.js gets all the open windows along with the open tabs in each of them using:

```
function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {
  var tabs = [];
  for (var i in winData) {
    /*if (winData[i].focused === true) {*/
        var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
        var totTabs = winTabs.length;
        for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {
          tabs.push(winTabs[j].url);
        }
    /*}*/
  }
  console.log(tabs);
}
```

which was actually posted by bpatel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome). Now as you can see the commented line, it allows me to decide if the tabs are taken from just the current focused window or all the windows. My issue is that how exactly can I change this setting dynamically once the extension has been loaded into chrome and is being used actively? So if a user goes into options and says they want only all the windows I would be able pass a message to my background.js to say "hey use the all windows function and not the current focused window". I understand that 2 seperate functions should ideally be used here, this is just a sample on how it would be done. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to save any user settings.
The options page and the background page share the same localstorage, so you can update the setting from options page and access the value from background page.

**options.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="windowType" value="All">Check all windows</input>
<input type="button" id="saveSettings" value="Save">Save</input>
```

**options.js**

```
document.getElementById("saveSettings").onclick = save_settings;
function save_settings()
{
   var checkAll = document.getElementById("windowType").checked;
   localStorage.setItem("check_all_windows",checkAll);
}
```

You can use a similar function to update the value of the checkbox with the current value, when the options page loads.

**background.js**

```
function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {
  var tabs = [];
  for (var i in winData) {
    var checkAll = (localStorage.getItem("check_all_windows") == "true");
    if (checkAll || winData[i].focused === true) {
        var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
        var totTabs = winTabs.length;
        for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {
          tabs.push(winTabs[j].url);
        }
    }
  }
  console.log(tabs);
}
```

In background.js, you can get the value of the same key from localStorage and check if it is set to true or false. Remember that the localStorage will store values as strings so you need to compare it with the proper strings - if("false") will evaluate to true.