# From bash get list of currently opened tabs in a Chromium process

Tags: bash, ubuntu, chromium

From bash, I would like a command (or function) that I can use to get a list (one per line) of URLs that are currently opened in a Chromium window.

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome), but I think it requires creating an extension? If creating extension is only way, can you please give explicit instructions (ideally a bash script that creates the required extension)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving which tabs are open in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome)

Comment: This works well on Mac: https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli

Comment: @Skrat I do not believe it is a duplicate. That question does not mention Bash.

Comment: @Will nice find. that would be nice. Unfortunately I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: @XuWang Did you [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11915443/316622)? It states an extension is the only way and I doubt anyone is going to do your work for you by creating that extension, especially a bash script that will create that extension.

Comment: @Skrat thank you, yes I have read that answer. I think it is 6 years ago and Chromium development is quite rapid so I am guessing many things have changed.

Comment: An extension is not the only way. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/970586/167115). It may take some slight modification. The directories were different. I had to use the Sessions directory and in that directory there was a file that begins with `Tab` for each active session. Also, I had to change `chromium` to `google-chome` of course. For example, on Chrome I had to use this instead `cat -e ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sessions/Tab* | sed -e 's/\^@/\n/g' -e '/_\/chrome/d' | grep http  | sort -u | sed 's/http/\nhttp/g' | perl -pe 's|(?<!/)/[^/]*$|/|'`

Comment: I used the extra `sed` and `perl` commands at the end to clean up the output a bit and truncate some of the really long URLs and I think I removed something in the middle and added  `grep http`.