# Ensure URL is opened only once

Tags: browser

Ensure URL is opened only once!
I am currently programming a little program which opens an URL in the default browser every time I click a button. So with every click a new TAB is opened in the browser. So my question is: Is there any way to determine if the URL is already opened and if so only switch to this TAB and don't open a new TAB?

Comment: You have to use javascript for that purpose, Loop through every opened tab in browser and check the url, Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome

Comment: @HammadSajid you link is applicable if you create chrome extension. Won't work in site javascript.

Comment: you can use LocalStorage and it can be used via all browsers, it is not browser dependent. Reference: https://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/

Comment: @HammadSajid how locals storage helps in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible without creating browser extension.

Comment: This is security problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute of `a` element, or the [second parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) of `window.open()`

You can use them to make the browser always open the URL in the named window you defined while user click on the button or hyperlink
And use session to control the content within the opened window

Please know that this can NOT really restrict the user to "open the URL" manually (copy paste, add bookmark, etc.)

The restriction will still need to be implement with session controlling in the URL you're working